# Build a standalone ".tar.gz" Docker image without creating cache

Tags: docker, docker-build

I am generating docker images with the following commands:

```
docker build --no-cache=true --force-rm -t $TAG .
docker save $TAG | pigz > $DOCKER_CLIENT_NAME
docker image rm -f  $TAG
```

```
docker --version
Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc
```

I have two questions:

- can I have the three commands "all at once" with a custom builder? I am quite new to Docker, I saw there are several builder drivers, but I never managed to make the exact same file (.tar.gz with the same format (OCI?)) I only managed to have a direct tar.gz of the file contents, but not the image itself.
- Eventhough I use `--no-cache=true --force-rm` it stills generates a lot of build cache layers. How can I do to not keep them? I have to do a `docker system prune -a -f` everyday when idle (I believe it fails when a docker system prune occurs at the same time)
  I run this in a script ~20 times a day.
  Thank you!

```
[root@blabla ~]# docker system df -v
Images space usage:

REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE      SHARED SIZE   UNIQUE SIZE   CONTAINERS

Containers space usage:

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   LOCAL VOLUMES   SIZE      CREATED   STATUS    NAMES

Local Volumes space usage:

VOLUME NAME   LINKS     SIZE

Build cache usage: 4.085GB

CACHE ID       CACHE TYPE     SIZE      CREATED         LAST USED       USAGE     SHARED
zbl6sfoi1mnk   regular        33.7MB    6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
se5ieou1bpma   regular        689MB     6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
bsrwh7g7sm3y   regular        45.6kB    6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
7knpo8jf5xgl   regular        263MB     6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
9bhm3qvhy1xq   regular        24.2kB    6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
p30ycjl5wrny   regular        671MB     6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
44n78fr9apyt   regular        836kB     6 hours ago     6 hours ago     1         false
bult7i2wuqqu   regular        263MB     6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
iskdwlnbmjjn   regular        45.6kB    6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
zc16cmf04wd3   regular        671MB     5 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
bar49qm3yhfy   source.local   0B        6 hours ago     5 minutes ago   2         false
qhtgrakuz0tu   source.local   533B      6 hours ago     5 minutes ago   2         false
duvrvuth080e   regular        0B        6 hours ago     5 minutes ago   2         false
8oqc9tku8hwe   source.local   986MB     6 hours ago     5 minutes ago   2         false
psffwyhk0rtg   regular        33.7MB    6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
rvojp10g0c3f   regular        473MB     6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
sgnr8jasgy56   regular        24.2kB    6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
tsxslzka1em8   regular        836kB     6 minutes ago   5 minutes ago   1         false
```

`--force-rm` seems to have no effect.

`--cache-from type=local,dest=/bla/bla  --cache-to type=local,dest=/bla/bla` does not work with docker driver:
ERROR: cache export feature is currently not supported for docker driver. Please switch to a different driver (eg. "docker buildx create --use")

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to _need_ the exported image, or to avoid the build cache?  IME it's pretty unusual to need an image in a tar file (unless you need to import it into an off-the-network environment) and the build cache is almost never harmful.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David.
Yes, the generated images are not publicly available, they are distributed on demand to specific machines.
and the cache never stop growing, resulting in a disk full.
Is there any way to limit the diskspace/the availability of any cache entry?
The largest layer in the cache is anyway never the same : they contain generated binaries personalized at generation.